# Symfony2 Doctrine2 make a managed entity unmanaged

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

If I have multiple managed entities and there is a single entity I don't want it to flush how do I make it unmanaged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can detach an entity:

```
$EntityManager->detach($entity);
```

But, in most cases, this is not necessary. If you don't explicitly call `persist` on the entity, modifications won't be stored anyway.

Comment: You can also flush only the entities that you are interested into by passing them to the call to `flush`.